# Element not interactable issue because of chrome browser version update (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157) (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, coded-ui-tests

Unable to click on a page links via HREF, but can click via link text

As we have a different version of the website where we have different languages so can't hard code the link text as it is different for each but links HREF is the same throughout. I have tried to sync both chrome driver and chrome browser version but it is stated Driver 74.0.3729.6 is for chrome 74. session is started just the links click issue.

```
    public OrderPage NavigateOrder()
    {
        var homeHyperlink = new HtmlHyperlink(_browserWindow);
        homeHyperlink.SearchProperties[HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = PageLinks.OrderHref;
        Mouse.Click(homeHyperlink);
        return new OrderPage(_browserWindow);
    }
```

This code is working,

```
    public OrderPage NavigateOrder()
    {
        string keyToSearch = "Orders";
        var link = FindHtmlHyerlink(keyToSearch);
        Mouse.Click(link);
        return new OrderPage(_browserWindow);
    }
```

HREF code was working perfectly before this version updates,
I am getting this exception at mouse.click()

Message: Test method WebUI.CodedUI.Test.OrderTests.AmountExceed threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
[image]

Comment: @DebanjanB, this question is not above element visible or not, rather it is an issue related to updating of the chrome browser version.

Comment: Why do you feel _...issue related to updating of the chrome browser version..._? Can you update the question with the error stack trace? Did you have a  look at the duplicate target atleast once?

Comment: Yes obviously after looking the question I said it is not relevant, because the code was working perfectly before the chrome update. and the exception I am getting is also about the version issue, kindly remove the duplicate tag.